# Deploy GWT and HTML application

Tags: apache, gwt, tomcat, xampp, gwt-rpc

I have a simple site, that uses just four HTML pages. One page has a `<div id=main_container />` element. From the GWT application I use the `RootPanel.get("main_container")` to access that element. The GWT app uses GWT-RPC to connect to a server (written in java). My problem is how to test it on xampp, because if I compile the GWT app and upload the war files and put inside it the four HTML files, then I can access all of the pages except the one that contains the `<div>` element. I need some help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using GWT-RPC, you also need an `Application Server` like jetty or tomcat. Apache alone is not enough. 
If you are developing your app, there is no need for apache as you can run your whole web app in DevMode or just jetty.

In production what you want to do is set up Apache as a proxy to your web app running on jetty. Just to be clear, you cannot run a GWT app that also uses GWT-RPC on most shared host environments.

Comment: What do you mean by shared host environments?

Comment: For example if you want to run your app on HostGator or one of those hosts that offer a *shared* host environment. That's not going to be possible.

Comment: I have those four html files and a gwt application which runs inside the DIV element with id="main_container" of html page nr.2 .What do you propose to do? (GWT app must call a java service via GWT-RPC).

Comment: @Ponty I think my answer contains the *proposal* on what to do. You deploy your app to an application server (like Jetty or Tomcat) and you run Apache in front of the application server as a proxy.